# What is a full-table-tuple in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, tuples

Every time I want to insert multiple rows with PostreSQL's UPSERT in SQLAlchemy I use the following code:

```py
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import insert as psql_insert


data = [
    {'column_1': 1, 'column_2': 2},
    {'column_1': 3, 'column_2': 4},
    # ...and a lot more data...
]

session.execute(
    psql_insert(SomeTable).values(data).on_conflict_do_nothing()
)
```

But there are times when I want to use `set` instead of a `list` (for some reasons) and `dict`s aren't hashable so basically I can't. In the SQLAlchemy docs there is mention of something called [*full-table-tuple*](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/dml.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.Insert.values.params.*args) but there aren't any examples of it.

I tried executing this code with tuples containing column values in the order I declared it in my database models:

```py
data = [
    (1, 2),
    (3, 4)
]
```

but this doesn't work, unfortunately.

Have anybody used those *full-table-tuples* in their code and can show me how it looks?

Answer (score 0):

This is just an idea, but I guess a full table tuple needs to be of the same length like your table has rows - if your table has 5 rows, your tuple has to have a length of 5.

In a tuple of not the same lengh as the table row count, SQLAlchemy wouldn't know which rows you want to fill.

If you already use tuples of the same length as your table has rows, my answer renders useless.

On the dict part:
You should be able to acess your dicts like this:

```
data = [
{'column_1': dict_['column1'], 'column_2': dict_['column2'},
]
```

Comment: You're actually right, I have some columns with default values specified and I didn't include them in my tuples. I just tested it and it works perfectly. I don't want to specify those *defaulted* values every time though so if you have a solution for that, let me know